# SSIS derived column error

Tags: ssis, expression

I got this error while debugging in SSIS:

> > Error: 0xC0049064 at Data Flow Task, Derived Column [70]: An error occurred while attempting to perform a type cast.
> >     Error: 0xC0209029 at Data Flow Task, Derived Column [70]: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR. The "component "Derived Column" (70)" failed because error code 0xC0049064 occurred, and the error row disposition on "output column "EVENT_DT" (118)" specifies failure on error. An error occurred on the specified object of the specified component. There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
> >     Error: 0xC0047022 at Data Flow Task: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED. The ProcessInput method on component "Derived Column" (70) failed with error code 0xC0209029. The identified component returned an error from the ProcessInput method. The error is specific to the component, but the error is fatal and will cause the Data Flow task to stop running. There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
> >     Error: 0xC0047021 at Data Flow Task: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_THREADFAILED. Thread "WorkThread0" has exited with error code 0xC0209029. There may be error messages posted before this with more information on why the thread has exited.
> >     Information: 0x40043008 at Data Flow Task, DTS.Pipeline: Post Execute phase is beginning.
> >     Information: 0x40043009 at Data Flow Task, DTS.Pipeline: Cleanup phase is beginning.
> >     Information: 0x4004300B at Data Flow Task, DTS.Pipeline: "component "DataReaderDest" (143)" wrote 0 rows.
> >     Task failed: Data Flow Task
> >     Warning: 0x80019002 at Package: SSIS Warning Code DTS_W_MAXIMUMERRORCOUNTREACHED. The Execution method succeeded, but the number of errors raised (4) reached the maximum allowed (1); resulting in failure. This occurs when the number of errors reaches the number specified in MaximumErrorCount. Change the MaximumErrorCount or fix the errors.
> >     SSIS package "Package.dtsx" finished: Failure.

My expression is:

```
(DT_DBTIMESTAMP)(SUBSTRING(EVENT_D,7,4) + "-" + 
 SUBSTRING(EVENT_D,4,2) + "-" + 
 SUBSTRING(EVENT_D,1,2) + EVENT_T)
```

My original data are in this sequence:

```
EVENT_D: DD/MM/YYYY
EVENT_T: HH:MM:SS
```

Any help are appreciated. I have try changing my expression numerous time but still fails.

Comment: what DB did you use?? mysql?

Comment: There are some values which are not in the correct date format. Select 
CASE WHEN isDate(EVENT_D) = 1 THEN EVENT_D ELSE NULL END as [EVENT_D] from yourTable.Run this query and check if u get any null values

Comment: Ya praveen u are right, i get null value for every 30/04/2012 while i run your query. 01/05/2012 and 02/05/2012 etc are fine. How is that so and what should i do?

Comment: What data types are EVENT_D and EVENT_T?

Comment: In my source, both are varchar(11)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect that there are some date time values which are not in the correct format .So SSIS throws error while parsing them .

In order to find to incorrect date time value from your source table try to redirect the error rows from `Derived Transformation` and check the incorrect data using a data viewer

The problem with substring values are if the string data are not in the correct format then the `Derived Transformation` will throw error  .

1. In your OLEDB source component try to write the sql and get only the correct datetime values

Ex:

```
 Select col1,
        case when isDate(EVENT_D) = 1 THEN EVENT_D ELSE NULL 
        END as [EVENT_D],
        Col2,EVENT_T,other columns
        from yourTable
```

in your derived transformations use your code to convert into `DT_DBTIMESTAMP` type .

1. Else Try to use a script component and parse the `EVENT_D` and `EVENT_T` values and convert to datetime values. No need to use Derived column with all those `substring` values

   create a `New Output column` `Valid_D` with the datatype as `DT_DBTIMESTAMP`.Select the 2 input columns EVENT_D and EVENT_T in the `available input Columns` in `Script Transformation Editor`

VB.NET code

```
    Dim result As DateTime

If DateTime.TryParseExact(Row.EVENT_D, "dd/MM/yyyy", 
                          Nothing, Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, result) Then
     Row.ValidD = result.Add (TimeSpan .Parse (Row.EventT ) );
End If
```

C# code

```
DateTime result;
    if (DateTime.TryParseExact(Row.EventD, "dd/MM/yyyy",
        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None,out result))
    {
         Row.ValidD = result.Add (TimeSpan .Parse (Row.EventT ) );
    }
```

Now you can use Valid_D  column which is of DateTime type in your subsequent transformations

`Update` : The problem with your syntax is you cannot add date+ time in the string format . You need to `parse` individually both EVENT_D and EVENT_T .

```
(DT_DBTIMESTAMP)(SUBSTRING(EVENT_D,7,4) + "-" + 
 SUBSTRING(EVENT_D,4,2) + "-" + 
 SUBSTRING(EVENT_D,1,2) + EVENT_T)

So your syntax is not valid.
```

The `isDate` function shows NULL for `30/04/2012` because as per MSDN

```
   The return value of ISDATE depends on the settings set by
   SET DATEFORMAT, SET LANGUAGE and Configure the default language
   Server Configuration Option.
```

but it returns 1 for the value `01/05/2012` and `02/05/2012` because it takes as MM/dd/YYYY
so the 1st date is Jan 5th 2012 instead of May 1st 2012

So the soultion is use script component and parse these values into valid date and time and then use it in your subsequent transformations .

Please check my script transformation code above

```
Update 2:
```

I think your using SSIS 2005 .The code should be

```
  Public Overrides Sub Input0_ProcessInputRow(ByVal Row As Input0Buffer)
  Dim result As DateTime
  If DateTime.TryParseExact(Row.EVENTD, "dd/MM/yyyy", Nothing,    Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, result) Then
  Row.ValidD = result.Add(TimeSpan.Parse(Row.EVENTT))
  End If
  End Sub
```

after Script transformation ,you don't need to use Derived component .The result obtained in the column Valid_D contains the valid value which is of `datetime`  format

Comment: Hi am i right to say for the first suggestion, it will not includes all the 30/04/2012? but they are valid dates meant for 30th apirl. As for your the other two method what are they trying to do and where do i insert those codes? sry for my noobness. I am v new to SSIS

Comment: There are alot of blue underline when i add in the vb codes saying for e.g Row.EVENT_D is not a member of script component.... Am i adding it to the correct place?

Comment: You need to select the columns in Script transformation editor.Then the input columns can be accessed in the method Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)

Comment: I really did accordingly but still the same error
>>    Public Overrides Sub Input0_ProcessInputRow(ByVal Row As Input0Buffer)
        Dim result As DateTime

If DateTime.TryParseExact(Row.EVENT_D, "dd/MM/yyyy", 
                          Nothing, Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, result) Then
     Row.ValidD = result.Add(TimeSpan .Parse (Row.EVENT_T ) );
        End If
    End Sub

Comment: Update: it has no error now, 2 syntax error. So how can i check if the new column are in the correct format?

Comment: Since u are helping me, am i right to add a DataReaderDest after the script transformation? I still want to do sql statements after this step. And how can i preview the data in DataReader?

Comment: Why do u need a DataReader destination ?R u consuming this data to some other application like ssrs ?? You can always preview the data in Data Viewer by double clicking  on the precedence constraint and selecting Data Viewer

Comment: If you want to write SQL inside the Data Flow tasks then use OLEDB command component

Comment: Ya finally someone on the same page. I am doing this ETL to feed to SSRS. I know how to do it in those normal SQL way, MS Access. But new to SSIS and SSRS. now confused what to add in the flow

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20868/discussion-between-10e5x-and-praveen)

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to do this without a script, you could have just changed your expression from

`(DT_DBTIMESTAMP)(SUBSTRING(EVENT_D,7,4) + "-" + 
 SUBSTRING(EVENT_D,4,2) + "-" + 
 SUBSTRING(EVENT_D,1,2) + EVENT_T)`

to

`(DT_DBTIMESTAMP)(SUBSTRING(EVENT_D,7,4) + "-" + 
 SUBSTRING(EVENT_D,4,2) + "-" + 
 SUBSTRING(EVENT_D,1,2) + " " + EVENT_T)`

Not having the space between the date and the time portions is what was most likely causing your original error.  You were getting

2012-04-3012:25:37

instead of

2012-04-30 12:25:37

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem while converting a string containing date to datetimestamp field.  It is all due to spaces in the field. 
So we need to check for space and then convert it to datetimestamp. 
Below is the expression for the same.

LEN(TRIM([Field1])) == 1 ? NULL(DT_DBTIMESTAMP) : (DT_DBTIMESTAMP)(SUBSTRING([Field1],1,4) + "-" + SUBSTRING([Field1],5,2) + "-" + SUBSTRING([Field1],7,2) + " " + SUBSTRING([Field1],10,2) + ":" + SUBSTRING([Field1],12,2))